# How do I claim my reimbursed tuition on my taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tuition

I got a 1098-T from my school for 2011. I pay the amount but at the end of the semester my company reimburses me. All classes have been marked as Job Related.

Can I use use this amount in my favor or how is accounted for? Does the $5,280 rule only apply when it is not Job Related?

Thanks !

Comment: Does the reimbursement for tuition show up in your income as reported on your W2 and you want to deduct the tuition paid so that you don't get taxed on it, or are you just looking to deduct the tuition even though you have been reimbursed for it? Business-related expenses (e.g. travel) properly accounted for and reimbursed by the employer shouldn't show up on your W2 even if your company pays you $60 per diem for meals while traveling in lieu of actual meal expenses but you are on a diet and spent less on meals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the employer included the reimbursement in the taxable wages portion of your w2 then you can take a deduction.  This is most likely not the case.

If the reimbursement is not included in your taxable wages then just leave the 1098 off your return. You are not entitled to any tax benefit because of it.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can't. You've been reimbursed, you can't claim deduction for something you haven't paid.

Comment: Civility, please.  Prior comments deleted.

Comment: I have no wish to get in a fruitless shouting match again, but this answer is incomplete.  

Don't take it from me take it from the [irs](http://www.irs.gov/faqs/faq/0,,id=199721,00.html)